# no implicit conversion of false into String> in `include?'

Tags: ruby, typeerror

I got a little problem with a chatbot command that I'm trying to develop

```
match /^kill (.*)|^kill/, :method => :kill 
   def kill(user, target)
      target = target
      name = user.name
       if target.to_s.include? name || target.to_s.empty?
         require 'erb' 
         phrases = ["<%= name %> (gun) Se pegó un tiro porque el nestea con cloro no funcionó"]
         name = user.name
         target = target
         random_phrase = ERB.new(phrases.sample).result(binding)
         @client.send_msg random_phrase 
       elsif target.include? ['chat', 'todo', 'mundo']
         require 'erb' 
         phrases = ["<%= name %> se arrechó y le cayó a tiros a todo el mundo (gun)"]
         name = user.name
         target = target
         random_phrase = ERB.new(phrases.sample).result(binding)
         @client.send_msg random_phrase 
       else 
        require 'erb' 
         phrases = ["<%= name %> (gun) le pegó un tiro a <%= target %> por haberle robado memes"]
         name = user.name
         target = target
         random_phrase = ERB.new(phrases.sample).result(binding)
         @client.send_msg random_phrase 
        end
     end
```

Here I got two errors, but I don't find out how to solve them

```
#<TypeError: no implicit conversion of false into String> in `include?'
#<TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into String> in `include?
```

I have tried many things but I don't manage this to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `String#include?` takes String so that it will convert your parameter to String if its not String.

The first error `no implicit conversion of false into String` comes from `target.to_s.include? name && target.to_s.empty?`. According to [ruby's operators precedence](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html), the AND operator will be calculated first that leads to the Boolean value is passed to your `include?` function. You can fix this by modifying to `target.to_s.include?(name) && target.to_s.empty?`.

The second one, you should use `Array#include?` instead of `String#include?`. You might write this way: `['chat', 'todo', 'mundo'].include? target`

Answer (score 0):

`name && target.to_s.empty?` returns a boolean, which you then pass to `include?`. However, `String#include?` takes a `String` as an argument, not a boolean.

Comment: The error happens in    
`if target.to_s.include? name && target.to_s.empty?`
at least the first one 
`#<TypeError: no implicit conversion of false into String> in `include?'`